# SQL Server error 916

Tags: sql-server-2005

I get this error when I try to attach a database.

> error message: An exception occured
>   while executing transact sql statement
>   or batch.

I have copied my database in the Data folder of an SQL Server server. I want to configure the database in SQL Server, but when I try to attach the database, it gives the error.

I have also tried to change the permissions related to the database.

Comment: Is the database file from a newer SQL Server version that what you're trying to attach it to?? E.g. are you trying to attach a MDF file from a SQL Server 2008 to a SQL Server 2005 ??

Answer (score 4):

The error you're getting and error 916 are different! (I am not an expert, I just read over the Internet.)

`error 916` is this:

> The server principal “username” is not
>   able to access the database
>   “databasename” under the current
>   security context. (Microsoft SQL
>   Server, Error: 916)

Anyway, to resolve the 916 error:

1. After starting Management Studio 2008, select Databases in the Object Explorer once.
2. If the Object Explorer Details are not already showing, select View from the toolbar then select Object Explorer Details.
3. Right click on any column header and make sure that “collation” is not checked.
4. Refresh the database list by clicking the Refresh button located at the top of the Object Explorer Details panel.  You should have now have full access to your database at this point.

I (shamefully) copied from *[Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 916](http://www.activeservers.com/page13702330.aspx)* and *[Resolving Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 916](http://support.gearhost.com/KB/a451/resolving-microsoft-sql-server-error-916.aspx)*.

And to solve the error you've written in your explanation try *[You may receive error messages when you use the Configure Distribution Wizard in SQL Server 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914779)*.

I hope it helped!

Comment: okay, I'm no sql expert, try out both the solutions and let me know if it helped !

Comment: i tried doing but right clicking the Replication folder does not show me option for Configure Distribution or Distributor Properties either.

Comment: Hey, I've updated my answer have a look,seems like a service pack issue.