# Microsoft SQL Server, Error 916

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Studio Express. I have detached one of my databases (it was in my office server) and `.mdf` and `.ldf` files are saved to `MSSQL` folder (on my local server). While I was detaching the database it was saying that with my connections (hopefully the server) cannot detach the database. Then I selected the drop connections option in the detach mode.

Now when I try to attach the database it doesn't allow me to attach. When I click the add button doesn't give me the option to browse my folder. Below error message is showing.

> Failed to retrieve data for this request.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> Additional information:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.(Microsoft SQL server. connectionInfo).
>
> The server principal "my username" is not able to access the database "model" under the current security context.(Microsoft SQL server, Error:916).

What should I do? Please help me.

Comment: This post may be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603205/sql-server-error-916

Comment: Which user are you logged in with?

Comment: I have tried under my username and also with the administrator username. But both give the same results.

Comment: Once I use your create database thing it gives me this error message."CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

Comment: Once I check with the permissions on model. It gives the below message. "The server principal "my username" is not able to access the database "model" under the current security context."

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue... follow the given steps.
(1) Start sqlserver and login
(2) Press "F7" or click on "View->Object Explorer Details" to open Object Explorer Details window.
(3) You will see there column header.. like "Name", "Policy Health State", "Recovery Model", "Collation" etc.
(4) Right click on the header and unselect the "Collation".
(5) Now refresh the database folder. You will get all database list.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with the actual attach statement, but rather with setting up the wizard UI (which is a shame IMO). Use T-SQL to attach the database instead:

```
create database MyDatabase 
on 
    (filename = 'c:\Data\mydatabase_data.mdf'), 
    (filename = 'c:\Data\mydatabase_log.ldf') 
for attach;
```

You'd be better off to use T-SQL all the time instead of SSMS wizards. Or use wizard to script out the action and execute in a query window.

Also, check what's the problem with the permissions on model. Use this query to see if there's any `DENY`:

```
use model;
go

select 
    user_name(p.grantee_principal_id),
    dp.principal_id,
    dp.type_desc as principal_type_desc,
    p.class_desc,
    object_name(p.major_id) as object_name,
    p.permission_name,
    p.state_desc as permission_state_desc
from sys.database_permissions p
inner join sys.database_principals dp
on p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
where p.state_desc = 'DENY'
```

Comment: Once I use your create database thing it gives me this error message."CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. Once I check with the permissions on model. It gives the below message. "The server principal "my username" is not able to access the database "model" under the current security context."

Comment: Use sysadmin account to login.

Comment: Even with the admin account it's the same results.What I observed is when I tried to check the system database properties by right clicking on the system databases, only "model" database doesn't open the properties window. When I click on properties it shows this error message of Error:916

Comment: It's really strange, sysadmin accounts are by definition not checked for permissions against any object, for any action. This being the reason you can't `deny` anything to sysadmin.